# need a way to form the views of MVC website after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I am searching for pointers for developing a MVC web app whose views which will be formed after deployment and be modified if needed. I could develop an app where views will always be formed dynamically by picking paragraphs from a database, but I am afraid that might slow down the server. I am looking into the subject of scaffolding, but being a newbie, I could not be sure if that will answer my need.

Comment: do you use razor views?

Comment: As far as I know the Views arecompiled dynamically at runtime. This means you can change your Views after deployment without doing anything special.

Comment: I am working with MVC 5 which makes the use of Razor automatic, as far as I understand. I also understand that views are created dynamically, but I was referring to the templates under "Views" folder of the project, which can have static content. I was hesitant to make all parts dynamic.

Comment: If you want just static content, why you don't use just plain html? Maybe ASP.NET MVC is not the right technology. Or to understand the basic concept behind it you should maybe start with a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started).

Comment: I don't want static content; on the contrary, I got started with MVC to construct a website whose all content could be formed dynamically, and I also am following tutorials and have access to some books but I could not be sure if it would be an overkill or a hindrance to form every paragraph of every page at runtime (probably a few thousand lines for less than a hundred pages for a school website). I am searching if it would make more sense to form as much of the content after deployment.